# Is It Possible to Have Optional $select or $expand in REST API Calls?

Tags: javascript, rest

For example, if the `url` for the `GET` request is this:

```
url: domain.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Thing')/items?$select=*,Something/Field1A&$expand=Something/Field1
```

And if you're making multiple calls to grab different lists and one list happen to not have the `Something` field at all, instead of throwing an error and skipping over the whole request, is there a way to make these parameters optional?  I have an array of lists that gets called one by one to retrieve their list items.  There's a list that doesn't have that particular field so none of its items gets brought back.  I'd like it where if that field doesn't exist, then it can just go ahead and get everything and not worry about it.

The reason I even have `$select` and `$expand` is because it's a lookup field and I need to get the user's name or else just the ID gets returned.  Thanks.

Plus while writing this I wonder if using an `if-else` could work, but how would I know if the field exists before the request goes off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly know that these fields exist prior to calling the items endpoint, then it would be helpful to make a call like 
`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Thing')/Fields` and look for the desired fields. If they exist, then you can call your items endpoint with your select and expand params, otherwise you don't.

Comment: Would this be a separate call to retrieve `Fields`?  Currently, I have two calls being done for each list - one for the list itself and another to get its list items.  I'm worried about having an excessive amount of calls.

Comment: It would be an additional call prior to making the call for the items, but you might be able to get it from your initial call to the list, idk what you are doing there.

Comment: I get the list description from my call to the list.  I'm looking around and it seems like you can only get the list fields by going through that specific endpoint you listed above?  I couldn't just end it at naming the list and grab the fields that way?

Comment: maybe altering your initial call to be `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Thing')?$expand=Fields`? Does this give you all the data you want? You'd just have to look in this to see if your field exists, then decide to do a select and expand on your next call or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything!  I'm going to run with this.